# Copying column headings along with query results in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I run SQL Server queries from within Visual Studio, I sometimes need to copy the query results to the clipboard for pasting into another document. When I do this, I also want to copy the column headers (column names) along with the query results so that they get pasted with the data. I have always been able to do this with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), but I can't figure out how to do this in Visual Studio. It's quite time-consuming and annoying to re-type the column headings in the pasted document, and even though SSMS provides this "copy column headers" capability, I rarely use SSMS unless I'm on the TEST/PROD boxes. On my dev box I live inside Visual Studio.

So for example, say I run the following query from within Visual Studio:

[image]

In SSMS, when you right-click the empty gray cell in the upper-leftmost corner of the results grid, there is a "Copy with Headers" option right under the "Copy" option:

[image]

...but when you right-click the upper-leftmost corner of the results grid in Visual Studio, it doesn't seem to have that option there:

[image]

From things I had read, I thought for sure the **`Include column headers when copying or saving the results`** option on the **`Tools > Options > SQL Server Tools > Transact-SQL Editor > Query Results > Results To Grid`** menu would do the trick:

[image]

...but alas, even after restarting all open instances of Visual Studio, it still did not work. All the data from the query results does get copied and pasted properly, but the column headers do not get picked up.

**So...is there any way to copy column headings to the clipboard along with the query results in Visual Studio so that they can both be pasted into another document?**

(For reference, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Premium Update 3 and Visual Studio 2010 Premium SP1Rel, with SQL Server 2008 on the back end)

Comment: This belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JustinDearing I have never met a DBA that uses Visual Studio to access their databases...but lots of SW developers that do. I'm asking this question in the context of a SW developer writing code in Visual Studio and needing to run queries at the same time against the database via Visual Studio.

Comment: I've seen SSDT used at SQL Saturdays. Once during a talk about doing server side traces. I see your point though, SSDT tends to be used more by the devs and BI people than DBAs.

Answer (score 2):

I am running Visual Studio Ultimate 2012. When I choose **SQL > Transact-Sql Editor > New Query** I get a new query box just like you have. But when I right click the empty cell in the top left corner of the result grid I do get the option to copy with headers.

All of that runs off of the **SQL Server Data Tools** package that you have installed on your PC. I have version 11.1.30914.0. Maybe you need an updated version of the data tools. If you go to **Help > About** you can find the version of the tools you have installed. Check this page for the package [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015).

Comment: I'm actually starting my queries from Visual Studio's Server Explorer window instead of via the SQL menu. I did just run a query from the SQL menu as you mention and it does in fact allow me to copy the column headers. I really prefer how the Server Explorer window automatically keeps all my server connections listed, and shows all the databases, tables, views, and stored procedures in a tree view underneath. Do you know of a way to display this type of tree view when doing queries via the SQL menu? If so, I would switch.

Comment: Use the SQL editor the way I mentioned above. You can keep the server explorer pinned to the side to keep the view of servers and tables. To pin it to the side look at the top of the server explorer pane and you should see a pin icon. If it is facing down it will stay in place no matter what is in the main work area.

Comment: Yeah, I always keep the Server Explorer pinned. The way queries often start for me is...I will be looking at the data in a table (by having right-clicked the table name in Server Explorer and selecting "Show Table Data"), then I'll decide to join in some other data, so I'll display the SQL pane and start building away. This leaves me in the situation in my post (no way to export column headers). If there's any way to enable the "copy column headers" capability from queries started via the Server Explorer, that would be helpful for the way I currently work.